# Pip3 not installing (Already exist)

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I'm having Ubuntu 16.04 OS running in which, while I tried to install pip3 using the command **sudo apt install python3-pip** Its showing `python3-pip is already the newest version (8.1.1-2ubuntu0.6).`

But when I tried to get the **pip3 --version**, its showing `The program 'pip3' is currently not installed.`

Please help me to solve this issue, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing pip from your PATH.
Try running 'which python3' or 'which python' and see if you can find pip in the same folder.
You can then add it to your path if you want by modifying your bash profile or adding an alias